# How To Translate React Router Function to Typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I Start Work On React Project used react-router-dom and the client need to convert project code to Typescript

I Build 2 folder "RouteWrapper.js" and "ProviderRoutes.js"

1- "RouteWrapper.js"

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function RouteWrapper({
  component: Component,
  isPrivate,
  ...rest
}) {
  const signed = false;

  if (!signed && isPrivate) {
    return <Redirect exact to="/signin" />;
  }

  if (signed && !isPrivate) {
    return <Redirect to="/" />;
  }

  return (
    <Route {...rest} component={Component} />
  );
}

RouteWrapper.propTypes = {
  isPrivate: PropTypes.bool,
  component: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.element, PropTypes.func])
    .isRequired,
};

RouteWrapper.defaultProps = {
  isPrivate: false,
};
```

2- "ProviderRoutes.js"

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

// Components
import Route from './RouteWrapper';
import Authentication from '../Layouts/Authentication/Authentication.Layout';
import ChatApplication from '../Layouts/ChatApplication/ChatApplication.Layout';

export default function ProviderRoutes() {
  return (
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path={["/signin", "/signup", "/reset-password"]} component={Authentication} />
        <Route path="/" component={ChatApplication} isPrivate />
    </Switch>
  )
}
```

Comment: Typescript is a superset of JavaScript. So this already is typescript. What is the issue you’re facing?

Comment: In First File Line 6 and 7 "Binding element 'Component' implicitly has an 'any' type." and "Binding element 'isPrivate' implicitly has an 'any' type."

Comment: Are you going to ask us how to add types for each line of this code?

Comment: Yes Please, Sorry I'm confused with the issue

Comment: That’s too broad for stackoverflow (we could write a blog series on it)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is mostly in `RouteWrapper`. First, let’s assume you’ll no longer want to use
prop types, since types are now checked at compile time by TypeScript.

These are the basics:

- React is exported using `module.exports = React`. This means the technically correct way to import
  React is `import * as React from 'react';`. Alternatively you can set `"esModuleInterop": true` in
  `tsconfig.json`.
- The return type of React components is `React.ReactElement`.

Also it’s ok to use destructuring to assign simple default props in functional components.

For `<RouteWrapper />` specifically `component` is extracted from props, and then passed to
`<Route />` along with the other props. This means it might as well be included in the rest props.

Since the rest props are passed to `<Route />`, the type of props for `<RouteWrapper />` should
extend `RouteProps` from `react-router-dom`.

`RouteWrapper` would look like this:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Redirect, Route, RouteProps } from 'react-router-dom';

interface RouteWrapperProps extends RouteProps {
  isPrivate: boolean;
}

export default function RouteWrapper({
  isPrivate = false,
  ...rest
}: RouteWrapperProps): ReactElement {
  const signed = false;

  if (!signed && isPrivate) {
    return <Redirect exact to="/signin" />;
  }

  if (signed && !isPrivate) {
    return <Redirect to="/" />;
  }

  return <Route {...rest} />;
}
```

If you really want to use `propTypes` or `defaultProps`, type safety can be added using `React.FC`.

```
import * as PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import * as React from 'react';
import { Redirect, Route, RouteProps } from 'react-router-dom';

interface RouteWrapperProps extends RouteProps {
  isPrivate: boolean;
}

const RouteWrapper: React.FC<RouteWrapperProps> = ({ isPrivate, ...rest }) => {
  const signed = false;

  if (!signed && isPrivate) {
    return <Redirect exact to="/signin" />;
  }

  if (signed && !isPrivate) {
    return <Redirect to="/" />;
  }

  return <Route {...rest} />;
};

RouteWrapper.propTypes = {
  isPrivate: PropTypes.bool,
};

RouteWrapper.defaultProps = {
  isPrivate: false,
};

export default RouteWrapper;
```

Beware the preferred way of writing routes using `react-router` is to use children, not the
`component` prop.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

// Components
import RouteWrapper from './RouteWrapper';
import Authentication from '../Layouts/Authentication/Authentication.Layout';
import ChatApplication from '../Layouts/ChatApplication/ChatApplication.Layout';

export default function ProviderRoutes(): React.ReactElement {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path={['/signin', '/signup', '/reset-password']}>
        <Authentication />
      </Route>
      <Route isPrivate path="/">
        <ChatApplication />
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  );
}
```

This should help you get started converting the rest of the application. :)

Comment: First I Want to thank you for your response, I Try with your code put i found this issue "Type '{ isPrivate: PropTypes.Requireable<boolean>; }' is not assignable to type 'WeakValidationMap<RouteWrapperProps>'."